# Change unicorn ports using capistrano multistage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano, unicorn

I need to set the port of unicorn depending of environment. Something like this:

```
#config/unicorn.rb

if Rails.env.production?
  listen 8080, :tcp_nopush => true
elsif Rails.env.staging?
  listen 3001, :tcp_nopush => true
end
```

above code return this error:

```
[out :: 172.30.1.24] config/unicorn.rb:32:in `reload': uninitialized constant Unicorn::Configurator::Rails (NameError)
```

How to change the port according with the environment?

Ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to check environment variables

```
environment = ENV['RACK_ENV'] || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to load your Rails environment to get access to Rails.env:

```
# config/unicorn.rb
require File.dirname(__FILE__)+'/application'

port = case Rails.env
  when 'production' then 8080
  when 'staging'    then 3001
  else 3000
end

listen port, :tcp_nopush => true
```

Comment: config/unicorn.rb:34:in `require'
 ** [out :: 172.30.1.24] : cannot load such file -- config/environment (LoadError)
 ** [out :: 172.30.1.24] from config/unicorn.rb:34:in `reload'

Comment: @Rodrigo I apologize, I'm still stuck using Rails 2 these days. Require 'application' in Rails 3. Answer updated.

Comment: `cannot load such file -- config/application`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a namespace lookup problem. Your code is being evaluated in the context of `Unicorn::Configurator`, and you have a "bare word constant lookup" for `Rails` in your conditional (the `if Rails.env` part). You can force a top-level lookup by using `::Rails` instead:

```
if ::Rails.env.production?
  # etc.
end
```

Hope that helps.